# How to check if a single letter string in an array is within a separate string

Tags: python, arrays, string, passwords

I am writing a password strength checker in python and need to see if the password contains numbers, lowercase letters, and uppercase letters. Only 1 type is weak, 2 types are Medium and all three types is Strong.

The password is input as password2 and I have created arrays with all letters (lower and upper separately) and 0-9 individually input as strings in three arrays.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,
James

Comment: Use regular expression or try the unicode database using `unicodedata`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach to point you in some direction. This makes use of some utils like the `string` module and the built-in `any` and `sum` functions as well as type coercion when summing `bools`:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as u, ascii_lowercase as l, digits as d

def strength(password):
    return sum(any(c in chars for c in password) for chars in (u, l, d))

>>> strength('abc')
1
>>> strength('abc123')
2
>>> strength('abcD123')
3
```

Comment: Sorted most errors, I know however get 0 whatever the input. I am using `print(strength(password2))` to output the answer @schwobaseggl

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether I understand it correctly

```
# s is password input
has_num = any(map(str.isalnum, s))       # True or False
has_lower = any(map(str.islower, s))
has_upper = any(map(str.isupper, s))
n_types = sum((has_num, has_lower, has_upper))    # type count
```